# Grey spots when baking normal map (blender 2.83)

Tags: normals, baking, normal-map

I have a high-poly female that I'm trying to bake onto a low-poly version. However, grey spots keep appearing in some places of the face and hands, as shown in the pictures below. I've tried to fix it for several days (changing ray distance, using a cage, changing UV and seams), and taking the ray distance to 1m seems to help on everything except the aforementioned things, but I've just run out ot ideas on what to do to fix it.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

[image: Face]

[image: Hand]

Comment: sometimes you can't fix the normal map, in that case you can repaint with a correct normal color in an image editor, or mix several normal maps

Comment: will definitely try mixing normal maps. Thanks for the tip!